# Retain previous page field values on browser back button click

Tags: asp.net

My web application has two web pages page 1 and page2. I have a continue button in page 1 to navigate to page2. I enter or select some information in page1 which has textbox, dropdownlist and other controls. And I click on continue button to go to page2. But when i click on browser back button to go to previous page page1 i am loosing all the vlaues in page1. My question is how can i retain the values or information without loosing it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the page have the smaller client cache then the browsers keep what you have type on. (if you press the back)

Comment: Check It

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155623/how-to-have-form-values-same-on-back-button-click-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

one of the way is to keep those values in the session.
And load it back when you are on the page.

Comment: I would like to know if I can use profiles to retain the values. If yes, can you give me some examples.