# autocomplete=off on a text field kills it when using back button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I use angularjs in an asp.net mvc app which is not a SPA.

Inside an "edit entry" form, I have some fields that are set to autocomplete="off" and some don't use this attribute. When I load the page, all fields are correctly set to their respective values. The problem arises when I click a link to go to another page (full load since this is not an SPA) and clicks the back button to come back to the form.

Under firefox, all fields that have autocomplete=off are empty when coming back to the page. But sometimes they come back ok (less often). I tried under chrome and IE and it does work well with these browsers.

Known issue? Any workaround?

**Update**: if firebug is open (for debugging in console log for example), then the issue does not happen, as if a refresh of the page was forced (it blinks). Console.log shows me that the ngModel is correct when coming back to the page. Only the autocomplete/off fields are not redrawn correctly. I can't debug more since having firebug open shows demonstrates no issue.

Thanks

Comment: that's a normal behaviour. you click a link and comeback and you expect that all form fields are filled as you entered? The question is about how do you share data between urls. cookie, localStorage, session, etc.

Comment: Yes I expect it, and so far I never had to worry about it when I was not using AngularJS. I guess browsers do that nowadays and I had nothing to code with cookies, localstorage or sessions...

Comment: thanks for the update. I did the same thing with Chrome and event w/o AngularJS, when you set autocomplete="off", it does not fill up the form when you come back. You can test here, http://jsfiddle.net/ta8kZ/

Comment: Your're right. In Chrome (and firefox), your second field does not come back. It does in IE. My web page works well in Chrome so maybe Angular adds some magic that works in Chrome to restore the field and does not work in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly: you enter information into a form on a page, then navigate forward, but when you press back the information is gone?

I don't know the reason for the behavior in Firefox, but the workaround would be simple and dirty: Save the parameters in the URL or in the URL Hash. I prefer the storing the data in the hash.

You can throw in these two functions:

```
// this function takes in your URL and creates and object with key/value pairs you can read
function readFromURLHash(url) {
  var pairObject = {};
  var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
    pairObject[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
  }
  return pairObject;
}

// whatever parameters you want
function saveInHash(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5){
    if(typeof errorMessage === 'undefined')
        errorMessage = "";
    window.location.hash = "#?parameter1="+parameter1+"&parameter2="+parameter2+"&parameter3="+parameter3+"&parameter4="+parameter4+"&parameter5="+parameter5;
}
```

So before you go to another page (or anytime a input field is blurred) save parameters into the Hash, then, as part of the onload (or jQuery's .ready() function) you read in the URL and populate the fields.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // read in url
    var savedData = readFromURLHash();
    // populate field

    $('#someInputField').val(savedData.someInputField);
    // or with angular
    $scope.someInputFieldModel = savedData.someInputField;

});
```

Comment: Another workaround would be to save those inputs in session before redirect.

Comment: There is also HTML5 session storage, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155623/how-to-have-form-values-same-on-back-button-click-in-ie

Comment: Thank you @EliteOctagon. However, using jquery in read() does nothing (is it too soon?) and $scope is unknown there. If I try to set the value in the angular controller instead, nothing happens (angular seems to overwite the input fields later).

Comment: well, maybe you can provide a jsfiddle?